# Save Multiple Pdfs links at once

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download, file-download

Supppose there are links to pdf files on a web page as follows:

```
exam1.pdf   from 2004
exam2.pdf   from 2005
exam3.pdf   from 2006
exam4.pdf   from 2007
exam5.pdf   from 2008
```

The exam*.pdfs are link to pdf files that are free to download. Downloading each individually is time consuming. Is there a way to download these at once?
I do not have ftp access to these files. I use all InternetE, FF, Chrome.

Example of a page: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-04-principles-of-inorganic-chemistry-ii-fall-2008/lecture-notes/

Comment: Some download manager plugins/addons can scan a web page for links, add check boxes or other ways to select multiple download links and provide a way to download them all.

Comment: duplicate question? yes. But we have better answers here. Simple & easier for the vast majority of people... ie those that are not a superuser. Both threads should be "merged". Original question was generic, this one is more specific and so are the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You post mentioned you use Chrome as a browser.

From the Chrome Store check out "[Download Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf/details?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)"

> Download all files linked on the web page With this extension you can
>   download all images, videos, pdf, doc and any other file linked on the
>   web page you are visiting.
>
> You can choose specific set of files or use the filters to choose all
>   files of the same type in a single click.

- I have not used it personally

Comment: Download Master has been removed from Google Chrome Store. Anyone has a link to the file?

Comment: @AliHashemi The link doesn't work because that's linked to an old version.  Just go to the chrome store and search for "Download Master".  I just used it and it worked awesomely well.  p.s. as of right now the one I found was titled "Download Master 2016"

Comment: Requires a locally installed Download Master app to work apparently.

Answer (score 1):

For firefox, I recommend the DownThemAll extension. You can use the fast filtering option to batch download all files with specific extension(s) on a web page at once.

See:

- http://about.downthemall.net/2.0/#select-window
- http://lifehacker.com/239561/geek-to-live--supercharge-your-firefox-downloads-with-downthemall

Comment: This is really the best answer and i have used it for several years and it is simply superb. Downthemall firefox extension.